# Postgres Copy To CSV Array is double double quoted

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv

I am trying to export my a Postgres table to CSV. My table contains a number of varchar[] fields, eg

```
{CA4 0,CA5 7}
```

When export using the following

COPY (Select * from table) To 'C:\output.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)

The array becomes

```
"{""CA4 0"",""CA5 7""}"
```

I am not Force Quoting the field and if I do it has no impact. I would have expected the array to become

```
"{"CA4 0","CA5 7"}"
```

Can anyone help provide a way to get this as the output?

I am using a Windows 2016 Server and PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: The quotes in a CSV string need to be escaped. It's working just fine.

Comment: Well, a value in a CSV file that contains the quote character needs the quote character to be escaped by doubling it. That's the usual CSV convention. If you don't want that, specify a different quote character

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realise that was the escape character. Many thanks